# Value of a variable not being fetched in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have the following code snippet in Javascript

```
<td ALIGN=\"CENTER\" CHAROFF=\"1\">
<button NAME=\"Add\" TYPE=\"button\" SIZE=\"20\"  " + addButtonDisable + " onClick=\"processForm(this.value)\">Add</button>
<font face=\"Times New Roman\" size=\"6\">      </font>
<button NAME=\"Update\" TYPE=\"button\" SIZE=\"20\" VALUE=\"Update\" " + updateButtonDisable + " onClick=\"processForm(this.value)\">Update</button>
</td>
</tr>
```

Here on click of "Add" or "Update" buttons should call processForm(this.value) function.
The issue I am facing here is this.value is returning correct values in IE11 but when I try the same thing in Chrome or Edge browser, it gives me empty value for this.value. Why this.value is not compatible here? is there any other way to implement it here?

Below is the processForm function

```
function processForm(message) {
    if (!validate()) {
        return(false);
    }
    
    document.EMPLOYEE.AddOrUpdate.value = message;
    window.status = message;
    
    if (window.status = document.EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEEID.value == "0") {
        alert("Please select a Reviewer.");
    } else {
        
        var browser = IdentifyBrowserIE();
        
        if(browser == "IE"){
            document.EMPLOYEE.submit();
        }else{
            document.forms["EMPLOYEE"].submit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:jsp]?

Comment: "I have the following code snippet in Javascript" — Why are you providing that in JS instead of in plain HTML? You should use the live demo feature of the question editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: `this` in an attribute-style event handler on Chrome and any other significant browser will indeed refer to the element that the handler is on. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: (That said, `onxyz`-attribute style event handling is not best practice, not least because any functions used have to be globals, and globals are rife with opportunities to shoot yourself in the foot. Modern event handling is generally best.)

Comment: `addEventListener()` is the modern event handling approach mentioned above. You can find the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Why_use_addEventListener)

Comment: Also there is no need for `IdentifyBrowserIE` as far as I know. `document.forms["EMPLOYEE"].submit()` is [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms) since IE 4 and should be used for all browsers.